# QGIS 3 crashes when QgsExtentGroupBox.setOriginalExtent() is called

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Below is the relevant code. I am using QgsProjectionSelectionWidget to get the CRS.

```
    canvas_extent = self.canvas.extent()

    transformer = QgsCoordinateTransform(
        self.canvas.mapSettings().destinationCrs(),
        self.input_projection_cbo.crs(),
        QgsProject.instance()
    )

    transformer.setDestinationCrs(
        self.input_projection_cbo.crs()
    )
    transformed_extent = transformer.transform(canvas_extent)

    self.extent_box.setOriginalExtent(
        transformed_extent,
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
            self.input_projection_cbo.crs().authid()
        )
    )

    self.extent_box.setOutputCrs(
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
            self.input_projection_cbo.crs().authid()
        )
    )
    self.extent_box.setOutputExtentFromOriginal()
    self.extent_box.setCurrentExtent(
        transformed_extent,
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
            self.input_projection_cbo.crs().authid()
        )

    )
```

Below is the entire report.

```
h2. User Feedback
h2. Report Details
*Crash ID*: 8e827b9e58264385e7a945fbe0ac6df5b4daf9a5
*Stack Trace*

 QgsExtentGroupBox::setOriginalExtent :
PyInit__gui :
PyCFunction_FastCallDict :
PyObject_GenericGetAttr :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFunction_FastCallDict :
PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QMetaObject::activate :
QGroupBox::childEvent :
QGroupBox::mouseReleaseEvent :
QgsPresetSchemeColorRamp::clone :
QWidget::event :
QGroupBox::event :
QgsPresetSchemeColorRamp::clone :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
CallWindowProcW :
DispatchMessageW :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :

*QGIS Info*
QGIS Version: 3.2.1-Bonn
QGIS code revision: commit:1edf372fb8
Compiled against Qt: 5.9.2
Running against Qt: 5.9.2
Compiled against GDAL: 2.2.4
Running against GDAL: 2.2.4

*System Info*
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.17134
```

Comment: can you share the UI code coming along and the way to reproduce? otherwise a minimal crashing example (a code I could easily run to reproduce the crash)?

Comment: Quoting the docs: `When using the widget, make sure to call setOriginalExtent(), setCurrentExtent() and setOutputCrs() during initialization.` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/other/QgsExtentGroupBox.html Have you checked this?

Comment: @DenisRouzaud  The plugin is located here. It is the master. https://github.com/wondie/batch_gps_importer

Comment: @DenisRouzaud I also called `setOriginalExtent(), setCurrentExtent() and setOutputCrs()` but the error still happens. The error happens when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: sorry, I don't have time to get into the whole code at the moment. I would suggest one of the 2 things: 1) you paste here a small python code which can be run on itself to reproduce the error. Or 2) you use debug statements (with print) to give precise information where the crash occurs (which method called with which arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem is not on the above code. The crash is most likely related to me hiding the extent groupbox buttons using Qt methods. I had to delete them because hiding did not work as they still reappeared. The code below used to work on QGIS 2.18 but was not working on QGIS 3.2 and later. Anyways I decided not to hide it due to the crash. Thus, I commented out the code below.

```
    for button in self.extent_box.findChildren(QPushButton):
        button.setHidden(True)
        button.parent().setHidden(True)
        button.deleteLater()
        button.parent().deleteLater()
```